# Receive Error while running Access database on Windows 10

Tags: database, ms-access, windows-10, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2002

I have a database created in **Access 2002** which was working fine until 2 weeks ago (2019-02-15). I am running **Windows 10** with **MS Access 2013**. I received a compile error: `The code in this project must be updated for use on 64bit systems.` Can anyone please help with what they think the issue would be and the best way to go about fixing it?

Comment: Based on the error message it seems you may be trying to run a specific 32-bit type of `Access 2002 DB` on a 64-bit system... where, two weeks ago, was a 32-bit system.  To your knowledge did you recently update your `Windows 10` system to a 64-bit system?

Comment: 2 weeks ago the computer had the same operating system And the database worked fine

Comment: its [probably this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/983043/compile-error-the-code-in-this-project-must-be-updated-for-use-on-64-b)